# How to execute a function at a certain date in a web application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, auto-update

I am on a project using php and codeigniter framework.  I want to make changes in the database every 3 months. The problem is I don't know how to do it with PHP. I can activate a function when a user access a page, but I want it to be self-executed at certain date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can code your script in PHP, and run it with CRON (provided you are hosting your application in a UNIX/LINUX environment).

[Here](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/) is a WebSite explaining how to do your automated PHP execution with CRON.

Comment: +1 good link, but he will have to write a command line specific bootstrap for Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job (unix) or a [scheduled task](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) (windows) that will do this for you.

It is very bad practice to rely on a user hiting a page to do scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to cron, you can simply plant a code at your main page that checks the date upon every visitor, and do the necessary tasks if the current date conforms with the modulo condition.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a cronjob and make your own bootstrap file (you'll call this file and pass the class and method as command line params.

This is a quick and dirty way of doing it (totally untested)

```
// usage: php cmd.php users/cron
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli' || count($argv) != 2) {
    exit('Not enough params');
}

// Fake REQUEST_URI
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  =  $argv[1];

// include the index bootstrap file
require 'index.php';
```

Name the file cmd.php and setup a cron job to run every month.

usage:

```
cd root/to/directory && php cmd.php users/prune
```

This is just an **un-tested** example - but should point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score -2):

You actually don't have to use cron if you have an indexed page the crawlers hit, look at your server logs it's none stop. For example if you need to perform a task once per month save next month in a text file, when you get a match run your task. Put this in a page you know the crawlers hit all the time, when the month changes it triggers your script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! OP clearly states: `I want it to be self-executed at certain date`, without users. My guess is: without crawlers as well.